# UIScrollView isn't working with Auto-layout and Segue

Tags: uiscrollview, segue, autolayout, viewdidload, viewdidappear

in the ViewController (principal), i have a UiSrcollView called scroller. It works well when i start the app. But, if i use a segue (to pass to another view controller) the uiscrollview stop to works when i return to the principal.

ps.: I using the auto-layout

Anyone!? Please.
i try to implement the content size in the viewDidLoad and in the viewDidApper..

```
(void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)];
     scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);
}


(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead, eg:

```
(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thnaks.. that was great! But when i come back to the first ViewController the scroller restart to the top!.. Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to store the scroll position in prepareForSegue and set the scroll position in viewWillAppear to maintain the scroll position.